# Unrecognized selector +[AppDelegate count] - App crashes on NSPropertyListSerialization call

Tags: crash, count, unrecognized-selector

lldb says `+[AppDelegate count]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xe6a0`

At line reading: `NSDictionary *soundDataPList = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:dataFromPList options:NSPropertyListImmutable format:NULL error:&error];`

This occurred seemingly at random.  I ran the code and it worked.  I ran the code again and now I can not get past this call.  The call has been working for days through hundreds of runs.  It is only executed once at the beginning of the program.  This all happened after upgrading to Xcode 4.3.1 and switching to the lldb debugger.  I have not coded a single call to the message `count` on AppDelegate.

Comment: Changing the UIApplicaitonMain() call from:

`UIApplicationMain(argv, argc, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));`

To this:

Comment: `UIApplicationMain(argv, argc, nil, @"AppDelegate");`  Seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I know you have probably moved on, but I have gotten the same problem.  I don't know what causes it exactly but I suspect a problem with XCode 4.x or LLDB at this point.  Perhaps debugging 32 bit code, which is what I am doing and sort of wondering if you are as well.

In any case, the problem goes away for me if I switch to GDB.  Completely gone after that.